# Is there another way to write SUM(IIF([CONDITION], 1, 0))?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax, count, aggregate-functions

What `SUM(IIF([CONDITION], 1, 0))` does is very simple. So simple, that what I really just want to write is `COUNT([CONDITION])` (but that's invalid). Is there a shorter or more preferred way to write `SUM(IIF([CONDITION], 1, 0))`?

Comment: The alternative would be `COUNT(CASE WHEN {Condition} THEN 1 END)`.

Comment: For what purpose? To save a few characters? High level advice: there are _always_ better optimizations to make and better ways to make code more portable and readable.

Comment: Nah there isn't. You're obviously spoilt by other languages :P

Comment: @AaronBertrand I simply believed that there must be a better way.

Comment: @Larnu Any reason to prefer one way over the other?

Comment: Personal, nothing more, @J.Mini . `IIF` is just a short hand `CASE` expression anyway, so (by the RDBMS) `SUM(IIF([CONDITION], 1, 0))` would be parsed as `SUM(CASE WHEN [CONDITION] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: `IIF` was only introduced as a functionally equivalent alternative to `CASE` for users coming from other places (e.g. Excel/VBA) where they might already be familiar with `IIF`. If you inspect the execution plan you'll see they are the same under the hood. So the only reason to prefer one over the other is familiarity (or character count if you're counting characters, but that's a really bad reason IMHO).

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN {Condition} THEN 1 END)` is the most idiomatic way of doing it, but note that `SUM` would return `NULL` if there are no rows in the set. If you drop `ELSE NULL` then `SUM` will even return `NULL` if there are rows but none of them match the `CASE`. `COUNT` will return `0` regardless. In Postgres, they use the `FILTER` syntax like this `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE Condition)` which is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to move your condition to where clause.

```
Select count(*) from [table(s)] where [CONDITION];
```

The above only counts where the condition that results in a match. You will find that providing a query example will go a long way in finding a solution.

Best of luck.

Comment: I recall there being some `NULL`-related reason to not do this.

Comment: In your condition use is not null if you don’t want to count these. Provide more details about your condition to get a better answer otherwise it’s a game of Whack-a-mole.